# Using "compat" to import firebase from 'firebase' on v9 does not work

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I would like to just import firebase from "firebase" on my React project.
I know that there are some issues between v8 and v9, so surely I used compact to import Firebase. However, somehow it does not work.

firebase version is 9.1.2

And here is the site I referred to https://exerror.com/attempted-import-error-firebase-app-does-not-contain-a-default-export-imported-as-firebase/

What I used↓

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

Error↓

```
./src/Preview.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in '/Users/****/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/snapy/src'
```

here is my whole code↓

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import { resetCameraImage, selectCameraImage } from './features/cameraSlice';
import "./Preview.css";
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import TextFieldsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/TextFields';
import CreateIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Create';
import NoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Note';
import MusicNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MusicNote';
import AttachFileIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AttachFile';
import CropIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Crop';
import TimerIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Timer';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { db, storage } from './firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

function Preview() {
  const cameraImage = useSelector(selectCameraImage);
  const history = useHistory();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!cameraImage) {
      history.replace('/')
    }
  }, [cameraImage, history]);

  const closePreview = () => {
    dispatch(resetCameraImage());
  };

  const sendPost = () => {
    const id = uuid();
    const uploadTask = storage
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-template-curly-in-string
      .ref('posts/${id}')
      .putString(cameraImage, "data_url");

    uploadTask.on('state_change',
      null,
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        //Complete func
        storage
          .ref('posts')
          .child(id)
          .gedDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            db.collection('posts').add({
              image: url,
              username: 'test',
              read: false,
              //profile picture
              timstamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            });
            history.replace("/chats");
          });
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="preview">
      <CloseIcon onClick={closePreview} className='preview__close' />
      <div className="preview__toolbarRight">
        <TextFieldsIcon />
        <CreateIcon />
        <NoteIcon />
        <MusicNoteIcon />
        <AttachFileIcon />
        <CropIcon />
        <TimerIcon />
      </div>
      <img src={cameraImage} alt="" />
      <div onClick={sendPost} className="preview__footer">
        <h2>Send Now</h2>
        <SendIcon fontSize="small" className="preview__sendIcon" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Preview;
```

firebase.js where db and storage are exported.↓

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "1:***:web:***"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, storage, provider };
```

Comment: What are you exporting from that file? `import { db, storage } from 'firebase';` this doesn't seem to be a valid import

Comment: db and storage are exported from firebase.js, but even in the firebase.js, error says that "Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' " I added firebase.js below the question.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was -g which is global.
It was because I had firebase installed both globally and on certain projects. Running the 「npm i -S firebase @ ^ 7.16.1」 command on Root solved the problem.

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
```

after firebase --version, nothing come out, that is ok.